# Renderscript error "cannot find symbol ScriptC" in AndroidStudio

Tags: android-studio, renderscript

AndroidStudio (AS) fails to find the definition of ScriptC_invert when implementing a Renderscript (in another file invert.rs). It is placed in a directory src/main/rs and this is updated in the gradle (AndroidStudio folder). I am using Android SDK 33 which should still support Renderscripts.

I am sure there are no code-wise issues as I am consistent with several examples online, namely, the invert.rs contains:

```
// File: invert.rs

#pragma version(1)
#pragma rs java_package_name(com.example.sharp)
```

and the Java code:

```
ScriptC_invert invert = new ScriptC_invert(rs);
```

but I get:

**error: cannot find symbol
ScriptC_invert invert = new ScriptC_invert(rs);**

The build.gradle contains:

```
renderscriptTargetApi 18
renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
```

as well as:

```
sourceSets {
        main {
            renderscript {
                srcDirs 'src/main/rs'
            }
        }
    }
```

Anyone managed to get this running on current android/AS versions? Thanks!

Comment: I'm facing the same issue right now. If you found a solution I would be glad if you shared it.

Answer (score 0):

Try without Native build-script, and place the file at:

```
app/src/main/rs/invert.rs
```

Finally, try:

```java
import com.example.sharp.ScriptC_invert;
```